# Example project packaged in plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create a Eclipse-plugin that contains a example project of how the plugin is used.

Users should be able to go to `File->New->Others..`, then select `MyPlugin->Example Project`. The example project contained in the plugin should then be imported/created in the workspace.

- How should I package my example project and where should I put it so that I can use it (in the "Example Project" wizard) in the plugin?

Comment: I would look it up in one of the plugins that have this feature...

Comment: have you already created it and tested in the runtime workspace?

Comment: @ppeterka66 Do you know any open sourced plugin projects that have this feature? I haven't found any...

Comment: JDT is opensource, and you can get the source using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15636204/1667004).

Comment: @nikpon no, because I don't know how to package the example project and where to put it so that I can reference it. I cant find any info about this :/

Comment: Open help -> About -> Examples there's plenty ways to create plug-ins with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I know its not good practice answering my own question, but I think my answer is better then no answer, if somebody have the same problem.*

To do this I put resource (my the example project) anywhere in the packaged plugin. Then I put the plugin in a feature, and in the feature's plugin-list I checked the box "Unpack the plug-in archive after installation". This unpacks everything from the plugin package into the Eclipse's plugin folder. This makes the resources (like my example project) reachable from my plugin. Like this:

```
 Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(PluginId);
 Path path = new Path("examples/example.gif"); // RelativePathToResourceInPlugin
 URL fileURL = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);
```